# new line is not working

Tags: c#, forms

NewLine to get a new line for my code. but it is not working

here i tried

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string[] sss = textBox1.Text.Split(',');

        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string item in sss)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add("www.ebay.com/itm/" + item +"WAIT SECONDS=1"+Environment.NewLine+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:watchLabel"+Environment.NewLine+"TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Watch"+Environment.NewLine+"WAIT SECONDS=1");
        }
    }
```

is there are any wrong of using new line in c# gui?

Comment: help me plz. i am new to c# forms

Comment: I don't think ListBox supports word wrap. You will either have to custom paint the text, or use a control that supports word wrap like `DataGridView`

Comment: cannot we use new line in listbox?